# Using Document Object in reactjs on onClick Good or Bad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Is it good practice to use document object in reactjs onClick ?
I know about useRef, but if we have a parent component and a child component I want to access the child component element in parent componnet.
Do I really have to create multiple refs then forward them in child components?

```
<div onClick={ () => { const filtersElements = document.querySelectorAll(".filter"); ..restComputation } }> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

generally using refs and v-dom are better practice than manipulate real dom directly.

In most cases, and I really mean most cases, you would not need to manipulate the DOM. So Yeah it's not good practice especially in this case where you can use JSX very easily to conditionally toggle those classes inside of your render method. Doing it this way is basically not using React for it's main purpose which is keeping the DOM up to date with the state of your application. As far as what you need to know before you develop in React, basically if you read a little bit of the documentation you'll realize how easily you can utilize state and JSX to solve these problems a lot easier and in a way more maintainable and readable fashion.

One reason I might add for this is handling the UI state of your application without React and manually manipulating DOM is very error prone and hard to maintain. It will get out of control quite fast and lead to hard to debug issues regarding a poorly maintained state.

**So yes... passing multiple forwardRef is better.**

Comment: So can I also use context api like creating a state in parent component and getting the setState function in context in child component to update the state.
What you say about it ?

Comment: one or two level passing props is ok. but yes, even its recommended to use context api for preventing props drilling.